# Regex search and replace with grouping

Tags: regex, vim, notepad++

I have a file with hundreds of lines looking like the ones below. My regex skills were not enough to get the job done.
I'm trying to do this replace in Notepad++ with the search and replace using regex, have also tried (and failed) in vim.

This is my regex

> `public string (^[A-Z]*[\S]) { get; set }`

So I want to make the first line look like this

> `Foretag public string Foretag { get; set; }`

and all the lines following it matching my search term which is Type="string"

```
Foretag Type="string"
DagboksDatum Type="DateTime"  
Byggdag Type="int"  
PaborjadeArbeten Type="string"  
FardigaArbeten Type="string"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vim:

```
:%s/\(\w*\).*string.*/\1 public string \1 { get; set }
```

Comment: +1, it would be better if add `Type=` before `string`. of course the current example has no problem with this command line. Also I don't understand if one tagged a question with vim, why the other tag `notepad++` is still necessary? ^_^ just joke... nice answer!

Comment: Thanks. I thought about adding a more generic and solid solution (with more capture groups and different quantifiers), actually, but I decided against that and kept it specific to the sample in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You would do it like this in Npp:

find what:

```
^(\w+) Type="(\w+)"
```

replace with:

```
\1 public \2 \1 { get; set; }
```